# Segmentation fault with argv[1]

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

So I have a program which takes a command line argument from the user and uses atoi to convert it to a number. It all works fine until the number that is passed from the command line is more than 2048.

Here is the simple program:

```
 int no_of_elements_per_thread = 0; 

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {  
   int status;
   void* thread_arg;    
   void* res;   
   int i = 0;

//initialize
   no_of_elements_per_thread = atoi(argv[1]);
 return 0;
}
```

When I run the program for different values the output is as follows:

```
  [adeb1][open-19][~/pre2] ./pre2 2098
   Segmentation fault
```

with smaller values:

```
[adeb1][open-19][~/pre2] ./pre2 210

[adeb1][open-19][~/pre2]
```

Interestingly if I try to do a printf with %s without doing atoi I still get segmentation fault as well with argv[1]. So it seems argv[1] is giving problem with values higher than 2048.

I am using gcc in linux if that matters.

Comment: Do you declare no_of_elements_per_thread anywhere not posted here?

Comment: Use [`strtol`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strtol.3.html) not [`atoi`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/atoi.3.html).

Comment: So long as your printing stuff, try printing `argc` **first** (in its own printf())

Comment: Your code works fine for me. What compiler do you use?

Comment: @Duc, really, verbatim? What about `no_of_elements_per_thread`?

Comment: Yeah no_of_elements_per_thread is declared as a global variable.

Comment: I mean I do something like printf(argv[1]) only, which invalidate his hypothesis that argv[1] is giving problem with values higher than 2048.

Comment: There's something (besides the type of no_of_elements_per_thread) that we're not being told here.  I kinda suspect that the parm list is being garbled by the IDE or some mess-up of build parms.

Comment: A global variable of what type????

Comment: works fine at my end!

Comment: What do you get if you printf `argv[1]` and enter a value less than 2048?

Comment: @HotLicks it works then! see the **with smaller values** section of the question

Comment: I don't see the value printed out.

Comment: the OP does not intend to print the value @HotLicks he just does not want to see `Segmentation fault`

Comment: @HotLicks Of course I discovered argv[1] is giving me trouble in a bigger program when I was debugging with gdb. So I wrote a simple version which is the above mentioned code. Btw it works for values ranging 0-2047 as I checked with running a shell script.

Comment: Where is the seg fault? Use gdb and give us a backtrace or at least which line.

Comment: @Aniket - But I want it to be proved that "210" prints out when "210" is entered, to show that the parm is not getting garbled.  It seems to me that the OP may have somehow set a build parm or some such that's causing the first parm to be treated as a string length.  2048 is suspicious.

Comment: And as modifiable suggests, he should also check argc.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your declaration of `atoi`? Without `#include <stdlib.h>`, I would assume there is none.

You may also want to ensure `argc > 1` before using argv[1].

Comment: Actually, he should make sure that argc is > 1.

Comment: @HotLicks Indeed. My bad. Corrected. Thanks :)